# Plotting a graph with multiple columns

Tags: r, plot

I have a data set with 20 years in the first column (1990,1991,etc..) and each of the next 5 columns is a different state (CA,CO,PA,NY,TX). I am trying to create a plot with year along the x-axis, and the totals for each state along the y-axis, with each state being represented on the plot with a different color line.

I can do this fine using matplot:

```
matplot(population$Year,popAmount,type="l")
```

Where popAmount is a variable containing just the 5 state columns. Using the matplot code above, I can achieve what I am looking for.

I am wondering how to do this using plot() though, because whenever I try the same code using plot(), I receive this error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

My population$Year variable is just 20 years, and popAmount has data for each of those 20 years. Here is a snippet of my data:

```
Year    CA   CO   PA   NY   TX
1990    1234 1234 1234 1234 1234
1991    5678 5678 5678 5678 5678
1992    9876 9876 9876 9876 9876
```

Why am I able to successfully do this in matplot but not plot?

Comment: Why would you insist on using `plot()` when `matplot()` is the right function for data of this shape? These functions are not interchangeable. `matplot()` is essentially calling `plot()` for you. You can type `matplot` without the parenthesis to see the code it runs.

Comment: Just trying to learn how to utilize the different plot functions